# Dynamic GridView DropDown Lists

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a gridview with following fields

LECTURE ID,LECTURER NAME,SUBJECTS and gridview contains link Buttons to Insert,Edit and DELETE.what i 
need is, when i click, EDIT SUBJECTS columns should contain DROPDOWN Lists to select subjects.
if the GridView row is not in the EDIT mode or INSERT mode DROPDOWN should not be displayed and display only the subject taught by the lecturer.

Comment: Can you show us the code and markup of what you have thus far? It's difficult to answer a question with no clear objectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by making the SUBJECT column a TemplateField, as shown below:

```
<asp:TemplateField Header="Subject">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="subjectDDl" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="subjectLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

You might have already added ButtonField columns to invoke EDIT, INSERT and DELETE functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The trick with doing this kind of databinding is to use two data sources, one that carries the lecture id, lecturer name and subject id, and one that just has the list of subjects. You can do this with any of the DataSource controls - here's a demo using SqlDataSource:

```
<!-- First data source is the main data source for the gridview -->
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" id="LectureDataSource" 
SelectCommand="SELECT l.LectureId, l.Lecturer, l.SubjectId, s.Subject FROM Lecture l INNER JOIN Subject s ON l.SubjectId = s.SubjectID" 
UpdateCommand="UPDATE Lecture SET Lecturer = @Lecturer, SubjectId = @SubjectId"
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Lecture WHERE LectureId = @LectureId" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Lecture (Lecturer, SubjectId) VALUES (@Lecturer, @SubjectID)"
>
<DeleteParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="LectureGridView" Name="LectureId" 
        PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</DeleteParameters>
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Lecturer" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="SubjectId" />
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<!-- Second data source is the data source for the Subject dropdownlist -->
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SubjectDataSource"  
 SelectCommand="SELECT SubjectId, Subject FROM Subject ORDER BY SubjectId" />

<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="LectureDataSource"
    ID="LectureGridView" DataKeyNames="LectureId" >
    <!-- Setting the DataKeyNames property allows us to delete by using the SelectedValue -->
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />&nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
                <asp:LinkButton Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LectureId" HeaderText="Lecture Id" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lecturer">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("Lecturer") %>' runat="server" ID="LecturerLabel" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="LecturerEditTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Lecturer") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <!-- The label is bound to the subject text field from the LectureDataSource -->
                <asp:Label ID="SubjectLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject")  %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <!-- In Edit mode the dropdownlist is bound to the SubjectDataSource, but we also set the text value from the LectureDataSource -->
                <asp:DropDownList ID="SubjectEditDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SubjectDataSource"
                    DataTextField="Subject" DataValueField="SubjectId" Text='<%# Bind("SubjectId") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```